# Javascript: Only returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

I'm tinkering with an answer to fizzbuzz that returns an array of the accrued integers and strings, but *return* is only returning an empty array. I can print the array to console and that works just fine (i.e., has all of my intended alterations). What am I missing conceptually?

Code:

```
function display(){
let fizzbuzz = [];

for (let i =1; i<=100; i++){

    let by3 = i%3==0; // i is divisble by 3
    let by5 = i%5==0; // i is divisible by 5
    let output="";


    if (by3){output+="Fizz";}
    if (by5){output+="Buzz";}
    if (output==="") {output = i;}
    fizzbuzz.push(output);
}

//console.log(fizzbuzz); 

return fizzbuzz; // will return an empty array. But why? 
}
display();
```

Comment: You're missing a function...? Otherwise *what* is returning the array?

Comment: You can only do `return` inside functions.

Comment: Just tried in chrome console. If you wrap you code by `let fb = function() { ... }`, then run `fb()`, you may see it's not empty.

Comment: You don't do anything with the return when you call `display()` ... explain in more detail why you think it is empty and how you are making that determination

Comment: The above code doesn't return an empty array. I ran it on repl.it and it works. You may consider assigning Display() to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying the output of the function display.
You can do:

`window.onload = function() {
    console.log(display());
}`

or you can do,

`window.onload = function() {
   let arrayFuzz = display();
   console.log(arrayFuzz);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Like above return is for functions. Something like this:

```
function runFizzBuzz() {
  let fizzbuzz = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

    let by3 = i % 3 == 0 // i is divisble by 3
    let by5 = i % 5 == 0 // i is divisible by 5
    let output = ""


    if (by3) { output += "Fizz" }
    if (by5) { output += "Buzz" }
    if (output === "") { output = i }
    fizzbuzz.push(output)
  }
  return fizzbuzz
}

const array = runFizzBuzz()
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `display()` is working properly.
Maybe try `console.log(display())` at the end of the script so you can verify that it is indeed returning the array with some information.
Also if you need the array for something else you can store it in another variable. ie. `myArray = display()`

Answer (score 0):

WHOOPS. 
Thanks, guys. 
As soon as the answers started coming in I realized that wasn't thinking straight.